# Which stats are important for an ice tank in DC Universe Online?

Tags: dc-universe-online

Which stats are the most important for an ice tank with martial arts in DCUO?

My bet is on defense and heal, but I would like to have your thoughts on that.

Is there any difference if it's PVP or PVE? If it is, then PVP is the most important for me.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [The "tank" role in DC Universe Online](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14617/the-tank-role-in-dc-universe-online)

Comment: @Mark: Its not a duplicate. I saw this post before I asked my question. Nothing is mentioned about the stats that are crucial for a tank.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really "tank" as such in PVP if thats your focus, however if you looking for stats on a ice power sets for PVP then I'd go for "toughness", "might" and "Power". That will give you reduction in damage taken (toughness), more spell damage (might) and power for a bigger mana pool (cast more).

I play a fire tank, and I focus on "Defense", "Might", "Power" and lastly "Restoration", as I'm only really interested in PVE. But AFAIK Ice tanks aren't all about healing themselves so much as Fire tanks do. Thats the difference between the two classes I believe, one heals for mitigation, the other uses defensive mitigation spells.